# Find size in bytes of pickle file python

Tags: python, pickle

I have made a loading system in my game, and I need an if statement to decide whether or not the player should be able to load a game. I have decided that I can just read the size of my save file, and if it is not storing anything, stop the player from loading the game. How can I see the size of my file? I am using pickle to read and write the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

os.path.getsize('filename') would do the trick